# how to count the gridview cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to count the `GridView` total number, what's wrong with my `for` loop?

```
public void Bind()
{
     //Assign the datasource to GridView
     this.grdCart.DataSource = Get_Arealist();
     //Databind the grid 
     this.grdCart.DataBind();    

     decimal a = 0, c = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i <= (grdCart.Rows.Count); i++)
     {
         a = Convert.ToDecimal(grdCart.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text.ToString());
         c = c + a; //storing total qty into variable 
         c++;
     }
     Label2.Text = c.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Total number of what? Do you want the numeric sum of all the cells in 4rth column?

Comment: if i chg to int it also not work, ya i want sum the 4rth column

Comment: @Mickey no, I am asking what are u trying to achieve - what should be the final result? Btw, you look nothing like Liu Yi Fei

Comment: my column is a quantity, i want to sum all the row

Comment: Then don't auto-increment it. Remove `c++;`

Comment: it also no work if remove c++, i will get 0 @@

Comment: markup for the GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple change can be to adjust `c = c + a` to `c += a` but this is not your problem.  Attempt to change the code as such:

```
public void Bind()
{
    //Assign the datasource to GridView
    this.grdCart.DataSource = Get_Arealist();
    //Databind the grid 
    this.grdCart.DataBind();


    decimal a = 0, c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < grdCart.RowCount; i++)
    {
        a = Convert.ToDecimal(grdCart.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text.ToString());
        c += a; //storing total qty into variable 
    }
    Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(c);
}
```

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: <= if chg to < get result is 0~

Comment: try `for(int i = 0; i < grdCart.RowCount; i++)`

Comment: The Index out of range is occurring because `grdCart.Rows.Count == 0` which is why `<=` produces error `less than size of collection` and `<` produces no error and results in `0` which is what it was declared.

Comment: so wht i should declare?

Comment: Just to clarify the issue was with using `Row.Count`.  It was `0` which caused the index error.  Using `RowCount` was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal total = 0D;
for (int i = 0; i < grdCart.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    total += Convert.ToDecimal(grdCart.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
}
Label2.Text = total.ToString();
```

Comment: can you inspect the grdCart.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value and see if it is grabbing the actual value from the cell. does the cell contain text or a control?

Answer (score 0):

@ Ksdevc or may be if doesnt initialize the variable c as 0 and instead of decimal use float. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
decimal c = 0; decimal a = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= grdCart.Rows.Count-1; i++)
            { 
                           a = Convert.ToDecimal(grdCart.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text);
                           c=c+a;

            }
```

Comment: Could you trace the value in variable (a) for at least 1 cell that is nonzero?